# Java / Kotlin: Bug algorithm duplicate object

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a Products object, which contains an ID, NAME, QUANTITY.

I have an arraylist object type product, it may be that in the arraylist the same product appears several times but the quantity is different.

I want to combine all products of the same ID into one product and accumulate the quantities.

For example, I have a product:

```
Id: 1
Name: Computer
Qty: 3
```

And another :

```
Id: 1
Name: Computer
Qty: 7
```

I want to bring together and delete duplicates in the arrayList
Result:

```
Id: 1
Name: Computer
Qty: 10
```

Here is my code but it does not work completely ...

```
var j = 0
    for (i in 0 until products.size) {
        while (j < products.size) {
            if (i != j) {
                if (products[i].id == products[j].id) {
                    val totalQty = products[i].amountProduct + products[j].amountProduct
                    products[i].amountProduct = totalQty
                    products.remove(products[j])
                    j--
                }
            }
            j++
        }

        try {
            products[i].priceHT = products[i].price * products[i].amountProduct
        } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
            loge(e.message.toString())
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this block of  java code. This will do your work but its in java.

```
 public void removeDuplicates() {

    for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < products.size(); j++) {
            if (products.get(i).getId().equals(products.get(j).getId())) {
                int totalQty = products.get(i).getQty() + products.get(j).getQty();
                products.get(i).setQty(totalQty);
                products.remove(j);
                j--;


            }


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6

Comment: the application stops but not gives error, does not work

Comment: did you check products array data after calling this function

Comment: It does not finish the function .. I put a loop to display all the table after the function but nothing happen

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer in Java as I am not well versed in Kotlin. I see you are using arrays. I would suggest use a hashmap instead:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> productCount = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for (i = 0; i < products.size; i++) {
    int key = products[i].id;
    int count = productCount.getOrDefault(key, 0);
    productCount.put(key, count + products[i].quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing elements from the `products` list while iterating over it.

Consider if you have the list `[a, b, c, d]`. Your index `i` is `0`, and you remove that element. Now the list becomes `[b,c,d]` and you increase `i` to `1`. So the next element of the iteration will be `c`... you just *skipped* `b`!

One way to fix this is to iterate over the list form the last element to the first (so start from `d` and go back to `a`). In this way when you remove `d`, you do not skip any element of the list.

Comment: You have an example?